# Do calls on the 1.1 API and the 2.0 count against each other's limits?

Tags: support, api, api-v2, limits, api-v1.1

Do the old 1.1 API and new 2.0 share limits?

Or do my Stack Apps running on 1.1 calls not affect my limits for apps running on 2.0 calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ip, and user/app-pair quotas are separate in V1.x and V2.0.

The "30 simultaneous requests" throttle is not, as it's a DOS counter measure.