# Would implementing both 1.1 and 2.0 APIs in an app/script to get around the API quotas be considered abuse?

Tags: support, api-v2, limits, abuse, api-v1.1

In another question I asked it was established that

> [The IP, and user/app-pair quotas are separate in V1.x and V2.0.](https://stackapps.com/questions/2911/do-calls-on-the-1-1-api-and-the-2-0-count-against-each-others-limits)

So with this in mind would an app or script which implemented like methods for both APIs as a way to extend their quotas be considered to be breaking the API rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, explicitly working around the quota system would be considered abuse.  Simply shipping an application that makes requests against both V1.x and V2.0 isn't, though I wouldn't encourage it (outside of the narrow case of moving an *existing* V1.x app onto V2.0 over multiple releases).

Also, remember that V1.x's days are numbered.  Once we're confident in 2.0, we'll begin the long, slow process of reaching out and convincing existing users to transition off of V1.x; and once usage is low enough we'll kill it off.